# Cordova project code hot update

Tags: android, cordova

I got a strange problem about cordova hotcode update and I've tried for a few days but there's no such a solution.

The problem is my cordova project only updated once from my changed html files on my server after the APP first time installed and launched. And if I uninstall it and install again, the final change(the last time i made something change in my html files) worked. So if i didnt uninstall this app, nothing would change.

Here is what i've done :

1. `cordova prepare android`.
2. `cordova-hcp build`
3. Modify config.xml with:

   ```
   <chcp>
     <config-file url="http://xxxxxxxx/hotcodeDir/chcp.json" />
   </chcp>
   ```
4. build .apk file
5. add some code in index.html file.
6. `cordova-hcp server`
7. change `chcp.json` to

   ```
   {
         "autogenerated": true,
         "release": "2017.xx.xx.xxxx",
         "content_url": "http://xxxxxxxx/hotcodeDir",
         "update": "now",
   ```

   }
8. copy all files under www directory to my server directory `http://xxxxxxxx/hotcodeDir/`
9. First time install my .apk file, and after a second, something changed on the phone screen, and that's what i want.

I wanna make a second change, so i do step 5~9 again, and finally, nothing changed on my phone screen.

So i changed html files 2 times and deploy them on server 2 times,but only the first time worked.

lets say there is an index.html file,and i modified it twice.

[image]

Comment: finally i modified somewhere in HotCodePushPlugin.class( Source code), and  forced it to update. worked.